# MySQL How to count and Sum condtionally

Tags: mysql, count, sum, conditional-statements

I have a result of MySQL after Joining two tables as follows:-

```
        ID              ||    Category      ||       Cost       ||
========================||==================||==================|| 
AMWP/ABC/2016-17/1      ||      1           ||      123.88      ||
AMWP/CDF/2016-17/2      ||      2           ||      222.99      ||
AMWP/GHI/2016-17/3      ||      3           ||      133.90      ||
AMWP/ABC/2017-18/1      ||      1           ||      100.10      ||
AMWP/CDF/2017-18/2      ||      2           ||      200.20      ||
AMWP/GHI/2017-18/3      ||      3           ||      100.00      ||
```

I want to extract summary as per Catergory and Count of each Catergory and Sum of Cost for Only with Condition where ID has Like one of ABC/CDF/GHI and Financial Year Like 2016-17/2017-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it the way I desired. In the following SQL, I am Using `Sum` instead of `Count` to `Add 1 to TotWks` whenever the Condition is `True`. Also, I just `Adding` the `Cost Field` to `TotCost` whenever the Condition is `True`.

```
SELECT
Category,
SUM(if(ID LIKE '%2017-18%' AND ID like ‘%/ABC/%, 1, 0)) AS `TotWks`,
SUM(if(ID LIKE '%2017-18%' AND ID like ‘%/ABC/%, `amwplist`.`Cost`, 0)) AS `TotCost`
FROM  <main_Table>
LEFT OUTER JOIN <join_Table> ON <main_Table.ID> = <join_Table. ID> 
GROUP BY <main_Table.ID>
```

If I Omit the `GROUP BY` Clause, then I will grand Total under `TotWks` and `TotCost`.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select category, sum(Cost)
        from your_tables
        where 
        ( ID like ‘%/ABC/% or ID like ‘%/CDF%/’ or ID like ‘%/GHI/%’ )
        and 
        ( ID like ‘%/2016-17/%’ or ID like ‘%/2017-18/%’ )
        and <joining condition>
        group by category;
```

Comment: Sir my requirement would meet with    ` select category, sum(Cost)
        from your_tables
        where 
        ( ID like ‘%/ABC/%’ )
        and 
        ( ID like ‘%/2016-17/%’ )
        and <joining condition>
        group by category;` but the MySQL is throwing error at `and <join>`

Comment: by <joining condition> condition I mean the condition that you used to join 2 tables. As I understand from your question there was a joining. If no just remove it.

Comment: I got what you are saying sir but MySQL is throwing Error.

Comment: Can we do something like this    `SELECT category, SUM(CASE WHEN ID LIKE '%2017-18%' then Cost END) AS TotCost FROM your_tables WHERE (Category <=3) 
GROUP BY  ID`

Comment: Sorry for delay. The error is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN'`

Comment: please give me full SQL as you try to run it

Comment: Got it sir with research and H&T Method.